# Running modern Python on legacy Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, legacy

I have some code developed in Python, which makes heavy use of Python 3 language features, such as f-strings (which require Python 3.6 or later).

Due to a customer commission I have found myself in the situation that this code needs to run on Windows Server 2003. Python has officially dropped support for legacy versions of Windows sometime around the release of Python 3.5.

Is there a "port" (I guess this would be the best way to call it) of Python 3.6 to legacy Windows, or does anyone have a good idea of how to get my code to run without doing too much heavy lifting?

Comment: Source code that supports older, unsupported versions of Windows eventually gets removed from CPython. Try the one of the MinGW or Cygwin ports.

Comment: I didn't think of that, that might be good enough for me. I'll give it a shot!